# How to create custom workflow container for designer wf 4.5

Tags: .net-4.5, workflow-foundation, designer, workflow-activity

I've seen the example where you can create a custom workflow container when rehosting but is there a way to create a custom workflow container that works in the vs 2012 designer?

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759032.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've asked same question recently and I've received pretty detailed answer on it:

[Workflow Foundation Native activity child activities on designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970113/workflow-foundation-native-activity-child-activities-on-designer)

I've managed to do this, however there was a small catch (you need to do the job from the link first to understand what I'm about to write next):

Design project output must be set to the folder of the project where activity definition is. Otherwise VS is not aware of design definition and you don't get any visual experience on your design surface.